# lisp: properly form if statement

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As a task for myself to learn common lisp, I'm trying to recreate [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15).

En route to recreating `_.chunk`, I've written the following to test for an optional argument

```
(defun _.chunk (array &optional size)
    (if (size)
        (write ("there") )
        (write ("not") )
    ) 
)
```

Setting `(setf x #('a 'b 'c 'd))` and then running `(_.chunk x)`, I get an error:

```
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA _.CHUNK
;         (ARRAY &OPTIONAL SIZE)
;       (BLOCK _.CHUNK
;         (IF (SIZE)
;             (WRITE ("there"))
;             (WRITE ("not")))))
```

What's the correct way to test for optional function parameters?

Comment: Well, for starters, don't try to call it as a function! The not-quite-correct-way (but good enough in many situations): `(if size (write "there") (write "not there"))`.   Don't wrap function call parentheses around things that aren't function calls!

Comment: The real way: `&optional (size 0 size-p)`: variable name, default value, name of presence-indicating variable. Now if `size-p` is true, then `size` was specified. Even if `size` is `0`, `size-p` tells you whether it was explicitly specified or defaulted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**size-p**, the name of the optional variable which may be specified after the default value of a keyword or optional argument, will be true if the parameter was passed as an argument to a function call.

so you could do something such as:

```
(defun _.chuck (array &optional (size 0 size-p))
  (if size-p
      (rest of your form...)))
```