# lisp: chunking a vector

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59042018/lisp-properly-form-if-statement/59042380#59042380), I'm trying to teach myself lisp by implementing [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15).

I have basically no experience with lisp, so work that would be trivial in js is foreign to me.

For instance, I'm working on implementation of a `_.chunk` method, which in js takes an array and a `size` variable and 'chunks' the array by the size:

```
_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
// => [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]

_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3);
// => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d']]
```

As somebody totally new to common lisp data types, I would assume that the analogous type would be a vector, not an array, is that correct?

Secondly, my way of solving this algorithmically would be to retain a `length` variable, and a `pointer` variable, and to grab a subset of the array/vector, [pointer to pointer + size], while pointer + size was < length, and then return [pointer to length] when that was no longer true, and incrementing pointer to pointer + size + 1 otherwise.

No idea how to implement this in lisp, here is my code so far.

```
(defun _.chunk (vector &optional (size 1 size-p))
   (if (or (not size-p) (eq size 1)) 
        vector
        ((let   (                    
                    (array_length (array-total-size array))
                    (pointer)
                )
            ???
        ))      
    )  
)
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use `subseq` to take chunks of our sequence... (vectors are arrays which are sequences)

Comment: makes sense, but... how do I do that?

Comment: The arguments are poorly ordered in the following regard. If you put the chunk size first as in  `(chunk 2 list)` then you may be able to use partial application libraries more easily. That is to say, you're likely too want to bind the chunk size, but leave the list as a free argument. Make the likely-to-be-free argument the rightmost one.

Comment: lodash looks like it may have been inspired by the Emacs Lisp `dash.el` package, which might be of interest to you. Anothe remark: the `_.` naming makes little sense in Lisp; you're better off giving these functions nice, simple names and putting them in a package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this implementation I would first write an idiomatic Common Lisp version of chunk that can be useful in a CL program (efficient, etc.), and then write a thin *lodash* layer that only wraps around those functions.

For example, I would first write a helper function to allow sharing storage with the chunked vector. A displaced array refers to another array but with an offset and different size. It may be useful to have chunks be only views of the original vector, so that they all share the same underlying storage array. It is not only a memory optimization: the behaviour is different when mutating either a chunk or the original vector, since any change in one is visible in the other.  But as far as I know lodash is (was?) a pure functional language, so it makes sense to share some data if you don't mutate them. Some languages call those kind of indirect arrays "slices".

```
(defun slice (vector start end)
  (make-array (- end start)
              :element-type (array-element-type vector)
              :displaced-to vector
              :displaced-index-offset start))
```

So I would also make `chunk-vector` accept `:start` and `:end` parameters, as commonly done, along with `sharedp` which specifies if storage should be shared with the original vector:

```
(defun chunk-vector (size vector &key start end sharedp)
  (check-type size (integer 1))
  (loop
     with slicer = (if sharedp #'slice #'subseq)
     and low = (or start 0)
     and high = (or end (length vector))
     for s from low below high by size
     for e from (+ low size) by size
     collect (funcall slicer vector s (min e high))))
```

*Note*: I assume `nil` is a possible value for `end` that means the end of the vector, to mirror how `subseq` works. I do the same for `start`, because for those variables the nil value can be used without ambiguity to mean "default value". I could also have defined defaults in the lambda list, as done in tfb's answer.

Here are some tests:

```
(chunk-vector 3 #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) :sharedp t)
(#(0 1 2) #(3 4 5) #(6 7 8) #(9))

(chunk-vector 2 #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(#(0 1) #(2 3) #(4 5) #(6 7) #(8 9))

(chunk-vector 1 #(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9))
(#(0) #(1) #(2) #(3) #(4) #(5) #(6) #(7) #(8) #(9))
```

Likewise, you could also define a `chunk-list` function and have the *lodash* `chunck` function dispatch to each specialized version based on the sequence type.

This can be done with CLOS, but since that is already demonstrated in another answer, I'll just define individual specialized functions.

Here is an implementation of `chunk-list` that is based on [`LDIFF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ldiffc.htm).
I tried first mixing all cases in one function, but this becomes needlessly complex.

Here is first an unbounded chunk function:

```
(defun chunk-list/unbounded (size list)
  (loop
     for front = list then next
     for next = (nthcdr size front)
     collect (ldiff front next)
     while next))
```

- `front` is defined as initially `list`, then the current value of `next` at each step
- `next` is the next chunk, computed using `size`; this plays nicely with lists that have not enough elements, since in that case `nthcdr` just returns the remaining elements.

A bit more complex case is required to handle the `end` argument, and for that we define the *bounded* version where there is also an additional `upper-limit` counter, that decreases by `size` at each step of iteration. It represents remaining number of elements to add, and is used along with size to compute `(min size upper-limit)`, the size of the next chunk:

```
(defun chunk-list/bounded (size list upper-limit)
  (loop
     for front = list then next
     for next = (nthcdr (min size upper-limit) front)
     collect (ldiff front next)
     do (decf upper-limit size)
     while (and next (plusp upper-limit))))
```

Finally, `chunk-list` dispatches on both versions based on whether `end` is nil or not; the calls are inlined here (because we can):

```
(defun chunk-list (size list &key (start 0) end)
  (declare (inline check-list/bounded check-list/simple))
  (check-type size (integer 1))
  (let ((list (nthcdr start list)))
    (when list
      (if end
          (chunk-list/bounded size list (- end start))
          (chunk-list/unbounded size list)))))
```

Some examples:

```
(chunk-list 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7))

(chunk-list 29 '(1 2))
((1 2))

(chunk-list 2 (alexandria:iota 100 :start 0) :start 10 :end 20)
((10 11) (12 13) (14 15) (16 17) (18 19))
```

Comment: "`sharedp` which specifies if storage should be shared with the original vector:" -- can you expand on this? why isn't `slice` just an alternate version of `subseq`?

Comment: Also, dumb question, but how would you add `format` statements into the loop to see variable states as the loop executes?

Comment: Also, I assume that you could overload `chunk-vector` and `chunk-list` into one `chunk` using CLOS as in tfb's answer?

Comment: I edited the answer, but basically subseq always make copies, whereas a displaced array is just a view into another array. To print intermediate values I often wrap expressions in print, because (print x) also returns x, so it does not change the code much. Or you can add a do clause in loops to call format. Likewise my preferred way of logging things is to avoid format and do something like (print (list :front front :next next)) and let the Lisp printer do its thing instead of formatting it myself. Plus it can be inspected as a data if I really setup a logging mechanism.

Comment: so, sorry, in what circumstances would you use `sharedp`?

Answer (score 4):

i would propose step-by step slicing iterating over the chunk index (since you can easily find out the total amount of chunks), using `dotimes`.

this could look something like the following:

```
(defun chunked (seq size)
  (let* ((total (length seq))
         (amount (ceiling total size))
         (res (make-array amount :fill-pointer 0)))
    (dotimes (i amount res)
      (vector-push (subseq seq (* i size) (min (* (1+ i) size) total))
                   res))))


CL-USER> (chunked "abcdefgh" 3)
;; #("abc" "def" "gh")

CL-USER> (chunked #*00101 2)
;; #(#*00 #*10 #*1)

CL-USER> (chunked (list :a :b :c :d :e) 1)
;; #((:A) (:B) (:C) (:D) (:E))

CL-USER> (chunked (list :a :b :c :d :e) 4)
;; #((:A :B :C :D) (:E))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to coredump's answer, as well as referring to a comment by Kaz.  Most of this is about style, which is always a matter of opinion and I do not claim my opinion is better than theirs: I just think it is interesting to talk about the choices as Lisp programming is very much about style choice, since the language is so flexible compared to most others.  The last section ('extending') might be interesting however.

### Argument order

The problem with a signature which is `(size vector ...)` is that `size` can't be optional.  If you want it to be, it can't be the first argument to the function.  Whether that outweighs the easy utility of partial-application libraries I don't know (however, in the 'do the right thing' spirit, if I wrote a partial application library it would allow you to specify which args it was currying, so this would not be a problem).

So if `size` needs to be optional then the argument order must be `(vector size ...)`.

Further, since coredump's answer uses keyword arguments, I would make `size` be one as well as you almost never want to mix keyword & optional arguments.  So that leads to a signature which would be `(vector &key size start end sharedp)`, and I'd then write the actual function as

```
(defun chunk-vector (vector &key (size 1) (start 0) (end (length vector))
                            (sharedp nil))
  (check-type size (integer 1))
  (let ((slicer (if sharedp #'slice #'subseq)))
       (loop for s from start below end by size
             for e from (+ start size) by size
             collect (funcall slicer thing s (min e end)))))
```

This slightly improves on coredump's version by defaulting the arguments in the arglist rather than later.

### Extending `chunk-vector`

Pretty obviously you might want to chunk other kinds of things, such as lists, and pretty obviously the algorithm for chunking a list will be very different than that for chunking a vector, because you really do not want to repeatedly call `subseq` on a list.

Well, this is what CLOS is for.  First of all we can define a generic `chunk` function:

```
(defgeneric chunk (thing &key)
  ;; in real life we might want to specify some of the keyword
  ;; arguments at the GF level, but we won't
  )
```

And now define methods for classes we care about.  Firstly the method to chunk vectors, which is pretty much the previous function:

```
(defmethod chunk ((thing vector) &key
                  (size 1) (start 0) (end (length thing)) (sharedp nil))
  (check-type size (integer 1))
  (let ((slicer (if sharedp #'slice #'subseq)))
    (loop for s from start below end by size
          for e from (+ start size) by size
          collect (funcall slicer thing s (min e end)))))
```

And now, for instance, one to chunk lists.  Note this may be buggy, and there may be better ways of doing this.

```
(defmethod chunk ((thing list) &key
                  (size 1) (start 0) (end nil endp) (sharedp nil))
  ;; This does not implemenent SHAREDP: this could only be useful for
  ;; the last chunk, and since you don't know if you could share a
  ;; chunk until you have already walked the list it did not seem
  ;; worth it.  It may also be buggy in its handling of END.
  (declare (ignorable sharedp))
  (flet ((next (lt)
           (nthcdr size lt))
         (the-chunk (lt p)
           (loop for c below (if endp (min size (- end p)) size)
                 for e in lt
                 do (print c)
                 collect e)))
    (loop for tail on (nthcdr start thing) by #'next
          for pos upfrom start by size
          while (or (not endp) (< pos end))
          collect (the-chunk tail pos))))
```

And of course you can now define methods on this function for other appropriate types.

Comment: what's the purpose of the `(check-type...)` line? to throw an error if the argument is malformed?

Comment: Also, given that you're overloading `chunk` here, how (where) does lisp determine which method to run if you call `(chunk {list object})` vs. `(chunk {vector object})`?

Comment: @lispquestions: [`check-type`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_check_.htm) was inherited from coredump's answer, and, yes, that's what it does.  For `chunk`, [CLOS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_.htm) [does the dispatch](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/07_ff.htm) based on the classes of (non-optional) arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The input could certainly be a vector (a vector is a 1-dimensional array).  Lisp has a few more sensible options of how to represent the result: it could be a 2-dimensional array, a vector of vectors, or maybe even a list of vectors.

To get a 2-dimensional array:

```
(defun reshape-2d (column-count vector &optional padding-element)
  (let* ((row-count (ceiling (length vector) column-count))
         (array (make-array (list row-count column-count)
                            :initial-element padding-element)))
    (loop :for i :below (length vector)
          :do (setf (row-major-aref array i) (aref vector i)))
    array))
```

To get a vector of vectors:

```
(defun chunkv (size vector)
  (let ((vectors (make-array (ceiling (length vector) size))))
    (loop :for i :below (length vector) :by size
          :for j :below (length vectors)
          :do (setf (aref vectors j) (subseq vector
                                             i
                                             (min (1- (length vector))
                                                  (+ i size)))))
    vectors))
```

To get a list of vectors:

```
(defun chunkl (size vector)
  (loop :for i :below (length vector) :by size
        :collect (subseq vector
                         i
                         (min (1- (length vector))
                              (+ i size)))))
```

This last version could actually chunk any sequence because it only uses sequence functions.